# How to obtain Heroku host url

Tags: node.js, heroku, heroku-cli

I have a nose.js pipeline on Heroku with review apps spwaned automatically for pull requests.

How can I get the url of heroku apps (`https://xyz.herokuapp.com`) at runtime using node.js or do I have to hardcode the value as an environment variable.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get the `xyz` part of the URL from the `HEROKU_APP_NAME` environment variable:

```
process.env.HEROKU_APP_NAME
```

Heroku sets this environment variable automatically for review apps if you specify it in your `app.json` with

```
"env":{
  "HEROKU_APP_NAME": {
    "required": true
  },
  "HEROKU_PARENT_APP_NAME": {
    "required": true
  }
}
```

See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/github-integration-review-apps#heroku_app_name-and-heroku_parent_app_name

You can also get it for non-review apps I think see, https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dyno-metadata